# How do you call a method from an external javascript library in a react class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grails, webpack

When calling the method from the northAmerica.js component class as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import $ from 'jquery';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class NorthAmerica extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        <script src='assets/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js'></script>;
        <script src='assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.min.js'></script>;
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill_en'});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"/>
                <script src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"/>
                <script src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.min.js"/>
                <h1>NORTH AMERICA MAP PLACE-HOLDER</h1>
                <li><Link to="/discover">DISCOVER</Link></li>
                <div id="world-map" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export class northAmerica extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(<NorthAmerica/>);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
bundle.js?compile=false:23794 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).vectorMap is not a function
    at NorthAmerica.componentWillMount (bundle.js?compile=false:23794)
    at bundle.js?compile=false:27669
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js?compile=false:27396)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js?compile=false:27668)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js?compile=false:27579)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js?compile=false:3177)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js?compile=false:27692)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js?compile=false:27579)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js?compile=false:3177)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (bundle.js?compile=false:28086)
```

I've also tried it this way:

```
class NorthAmerica extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.display);
    $(el).vectorMap({map: 'world_mill_en'});
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>World Map</h1>
      <div 
        ref={display => this.display = display} 
        style={{width: '600px', height: '400px'}} 
      />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

However, when calling the file from index.gsp (as below) the map works as it should.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Food App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'text.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css')}" type="text/css"
          media="screen">
    <asset:javascript src="jquery-3.1.1.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"/>
    <asset:javascript src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.min.js"/>

</head>
<body>

<div id="root" align="left"></div>
<br/>
<script src='assets/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.min.js'></script>
<asset:javascript src="bundle.js"/>
<div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill_en'});
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried including the assets and script src in so many places and it is getting bundled and shows up in the browser console when run... but the component still can't find the method. The northAmerica.js file gets passed to index.js as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import { CreateAccount } from './createaccount';
import { Menus } from './menu';
import { DiscoverApp } from './discover'
import { northAmerica } from './northAmerica'
import { southAmerica } from './southAmerica'
import { europe } from './europe'
import { africa } from './africa'
import { asia } from './asiaME'
import { australia } from './australia'
import * as map from './jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js'
import * as world from './jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.min.js'


ReactDOM.render((

    <Router history = {browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={CreateAccount}/>
        <Route path="/menu" component={Menus}/>
        <Route path="/discover" component={DiscoverApp}/>

        <Route path="/NorthAmerica" component={northAmerica}/>
        <Route path="/SouthAmerica" component={southAmerica}/>
        <Route path="/Europe" component={europe}/>
        <Route path="/Asia" component={asia}/>
        <Route path="/Africa" component={africa}/>
        <Route path="/Australia" component={australia}/>
    </Router>

), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any suggestions on where to go from here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have two different jQuery instances, one in React (loaded with `import "jquery"`) and one in DOM (loaded with `<script />`). `.vectorMap` is only attached to the jQuery instance in DOM, so you can't use it from React. You need to load the plugin in react instead

Comment: @Frxstrem This somewhat makes sense! I'm completely new to react... and javascript really. Would you mind giving me a little direction on how to go about doing that?

Comment: `resource(dir: 'css'` thought that was grails resources plugin (css won't change behaviour just looks so no fixture in comment